# Not sure I understand how R calculates the covariance

Tags: r

Consider this R code:

```
    a = c(1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,5,5,6,5,4,3,4,5,6,7,8,7,6,6,5,6,7,10,9)
    b = c(10,9,7,6,5,6,7,8,4,6,6,5,4,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,5,4,4,5,4,3,2)
    mean((a - mean(a))*(b-mean(b)))
    [1] -2.42524
    cov(a,b)
    [1] -2.518519
```

Why are these two values different?
Are the mean and expected values not the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the sample covariance function divides by $n-1$ while you are effectively dividing by $n$ when using the mean function. Try typing the following instead:

`sum((a - mean(a))*(b - mean(b)))/(length(a) - 1)`

The reason we divide by $n-1$ is so that the statistical property of unbiasedness will hold. That is, on average, we will not be over or underestimating the true underlying covariance.

Comment: @Nick Stauner - thanks for editting my post. Could you tell me how to make the R code look nice like you did?

Comment: NVM - I see what you did. All you need to do is put ` ` around your code.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go off and read about the statistical property of unbiasedness. I hope there is some rigor to using it and not just convenience!

Comment: Samuel - usually \` ... \` is used when writing 'inline code' - inserting code in the middle of a sentence. If you want to put a chunk of code in, after you paste it in, you highlight it and then click the $\{\}$ button at the top of the edit window, which indents 4 spaces, to get the whole codeblock formatted as code.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks - I will definitely make use of this feature in the future